# Jenkins deploying artifact to WebLogic

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, weblogic12c

Trying to deploy an artifact using Jenkins WebLogic Deployer Plugin. 
Getting following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Deployer
```

According to the documentation I should be using wlthint3client.jar (WebLogic version 12.1.3) but this client jar doesn't contain above class (Deployer), tried using the wlfullclient.jar which is said to be deprecated but if that throws another exception: 
        Hi, I want to install a war file generated from Jenkins to WebLogic, both on different machines, but when the installation runs an error is generated:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/deploy/api/spi/DeploymentOptions 
at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.init(Jsr88Operation.java:70)
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I solved it actually adding all of these three libraries to the Additional Classpath:

wlthint3client.jar:weblogic.jar:wlfullclient.jar